# Create add-ins for Access web apps

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2015, office-addins, office365api

I'm trying to apply instructions of an MSDN article [Create add-ins for Access web apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605890.aspx) to create my own add-in for MS Access web application. I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and MS Office Professional Plus 2013 installed but I can't find an **Office Add-In** template. I have tried to search for this **Office Add-In** template online (from within VS 2015) but I have failed to find it. How I can make this **Office Add-In** template installed for VS 2015 Update 1?

Please see attached picture for the step where I have got stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Latest Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/11/23/latest-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2015.aspx>) setup including project templates for MS Access Web Apps Office Add-Ins can be downloaded/run via Web Installer from this link http://aka.ms/GetLatestOfficeDevTools.